# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null React

Tags: reactjs

i am fetching the users from dummyapi. I want to list each user in a component before that i am trying to `console.log` each user with `forEach`, but it throws that error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null". I set the users value null at the beginning. After i fetch the data, i changed the users value. When i `console.log` it, users comes null at first then it shows the data. I guess first it goes into foreach loop when users are null so it throws error. I tried this, but didn't work.

```
{ users !== null && users.forEach(user => {
  console.log(user);
})}
```

This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import User from "./User";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const BASE_URL = "https://dummyapi.io/data/api";

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/user?limit=15`, {
          headers: { "app-id": APP_ID },
        });
        setUsers(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  users.forEach((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className="filter">
        <h3 className="filter__title">USER LIST</h3>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search by name" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please update your code, it still does not show the null check

Answer (score 0):

u can put question mark after user object like that so u check if user is aready
exist

```
users?.forEach((user) => {
console.log(user);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Run your `forEach` loop inside a `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  users && users.length && users.forEach((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });
}, [users]);
```

This `useEffect` hook will only run when the value of `users` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check first when you map the users like:

```
users && users.forEach((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });
```

#### A a bit cleaner and more testable case:

> **Note**: You can also wrap the function in `useCallback` function to avoid calling it when the `URL` doesn't change.

> 1. You need to initialize your user state like: 
>    `const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);`
> 2. When checking for users you need to check if the length of your user array is good
>    users.length > 0 && users.forEach(user => { 
>                // Your Logic 
>    })
>    or use a `isEmpty()` from a lib like `lodash` or `ramda`

```
const fetchData = async (url) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${url}/user?limit=15`, {
      headers: { "app-id": APP_ID }
    });

    const responseData = await response?.data?.data;

    if (responseData) {
      setUsers(responseData);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(BASE_URL);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is set the initial value to be empty array `[]` instead of null.

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

that way you don't need null check even if you call array functions to it.